# Simple query not using indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

My query is not using indexes.
It is a simple query.
Can someone explain why that's the case?

The query:

```
select TIME_FORMAT(start_time,'%H:%i') start_time,
       TIME_FORMAT(end_time,'%H:%i') end_time,
       rule_id, day_of_week, long_message,
       short_message, rotation_weight, mode
from timed_delivery_messages order by rule_id asc;
```

Explain Plan:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | timed_delivery_messages | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   22 |       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table:

```
mysql> show create table timed_delivery_messages\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: timed_delivery_messages
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `timed_delivery_messages` (
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_of_week` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rotation_weight` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mode` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'active',
  `long_message` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_message` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rule_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: With 22 rows in the table, why do you care if an index is used or not? And even if the table had 22 zillion rows, the query requests for all of them. The table has to be read, all of it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your query *is* using an index, the one that backs your primary key.

Look at the [EXPLAIN Output Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types) documentation for the "join type" column. The second bullet point for the `index` join type is what your select is using:

> - A full table scan is performed using reads from the index to look up data rows in index order. Uses index does not appear in the Extra column.